# Common Lisp: Run function in the background

Tags: multithreading, shell, common-lisp, sbcl

What's the best way to run a function in the background, in Common Lisp? Specifically, I'm making a call like
`(trivial-shell:shell-command "<long and complicated command>"`. This operation is blocking for ~10 seconds, but I don't care for the output, just the side effect - so I want it to be run in the background, so that program flow can continue. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in `sb-thread:make-thread`, but that didn't appear to make a difference.

I'd avoid getting wrapped up in all kinds of complicated threading, if at all possible. I'm running SBCL 1.1.18 on 64-bit Gentoo Linux.

Comment: Trivial-shell is an old and [rudimentary](http://www.cliki.net/trivial-shell) package. You could try other solutions, like [launch-program in UIOP](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/tree/master/uiop)

Comment: "but that didn't appear to make a difference.". Does your installation of SBCL support threads? check if `:sb-thread` belongs to `*features*` (or simply evaluate `#+sb-thread t` in a REPL). If it returns T, then you should be able to start threads.

Answer (score 0):

My little investigation: it looks like the only solution is Renzo's answer: the [launch-program](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/tree/master/uiop) function of UIOP.

Otherwise in order to run shell commands there is

- other methods of UIOP, like `run-program`, synchronous.
- [inferior-shell https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/qitab/inferior-shell] takes precedence over trivial-shell. It uses `uiop:run-program` so it only runs synchronously,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with `cl-async` and `bordeaux-thread` packages on SBCL.  Suppose you have a shell script `./echo.sh` at the current directory.  You can run the script at the background.  After the invocation of the script, the following code is immediately evaluated so you get `Waiting.....` on your screen.  After the script is done, the notifier is triggered and displays `Threaded job done.`

Make sure the `*features*` contains `SB-THREAD` as @coredump says.

```
(require 'cl-async)
(require 'bordeaux-threads)

(as:with-event-loop()
  (let ((notifier (as:make-notifier
                    (lambda ()
                       (format t "Threaded job done.~%")
                       (as:exit-event-loop)))))
    (format t "App started.~%")
    (bt:make-thread (lambda ()
                       (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/bash" (list "./echo.sh"))
                       (as:trigger-notifier notifier))))
  (format t "Waiting......~%"))
```

If you want to capture the stdout of shell script, add `:output t` to the argument of `sb-ext:run-program`.